# spring ORM and spring DAO

Tags: spring

what is the difference between spring DAO and spring ORM.As spring ORM is used for mapping with other frameworks such as Hibernate,IBATIS and spring DAO is also used for interaction with hibernate what is the major difference between them

Answer (score 0):

There is no Spring DAO module. DAO  ( or simply Repository ) is a design pattern ( Data access object ).

A DAO is a utility that manage persistence and data fetch from a data store ( SQL Database, NoSQl or even a file ) ..  so the caller of the DAO don't have to care about the technical aspect of the underlying storage system.

Spring ORM is a spring module that make it easy to implements DAO with ORM frameworks ( hibernate .. )

Basically you'll need to define a Repository ( DAO ) using spring-data helpers which relies on spring-orm helpers for JPA/Hibernate

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html